# Labeled Variables in Log Regression Function

Tags: r, function, logistic-regression

I created a simple logistic regression function, but when I run it the variable names don't come up as intended. For example...

```
#Simple Logistic Regression Function
logr <- function(y, x) {
model <- glm(y ~ x, data = gt2, family = "binomial")
print(summary(model))
exp(cbind(OR = coef(model), confint(model)))
}
```

I'll type into the console this...

Results come out with this...

```
logr(gt2$EDGT, gt2$age)

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ x, family = "binomial", data = gt2)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.8250  -0.8125  -0.7856   1.5902   1.7696  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -0.89974    0.16721  -5.381 7.41e-08 ***
**x**           -0.01962    0.02223  -0.882    0.378    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 434.32  on 373  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 433.51  on 372  degrees of freedom
  (3 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 437.51

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

Waiting for profiling to be done...
                   OR     2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept) 0.4066735 0.2916710 0.5623434
**x**           0.9805752 0.9370358 1.0228424
```

As you can see, the predictor is labeled as "X". How would I get it to be labeled with the appropriate variable name? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reformulate` like this:

first some data,

```
# reproducible data
temp <- iris
# y variable
temp$setosa <- as.integer(temp$Species == "setosa")
```

then the altered function

```
logr <- function(y, x, data) {
  model <- glm(reformulate(x, y), data=data, family = "binomial")
  print(summary(model))
  exp(cbind(OR = coef(model), confint(model)))
}
```

Now,

```
logr("setosa", "Sepal.Width", temp)
```

produces a result that ends with

```
                      OR        2.5 %       97.5 %
(Intercept) 1.490577e-07 5.094784e-10 1.582225e-05
Sepal.Width 1.202574e+02 2.769935e+01 7.166963e+02
```